# Searching for text in python without re module

Tags: python, parsing, urllib2

Im creating a definition in python that use urllib2 to download a status page and loop until a condition is met.

The status page looks like the one below:

```
reportId:327686
reportName:report2
status:Running
percent_done:0
```

I need to;

1. Parse reportId and create a variable with this value
2. Loop until status is different than "Running"

Can I accomplish this without using re module? At the end I will need to convert this to an exe using pyinstaller so wanted to avoid loading a lot of modules to keep the program small.

Comment: Is there more to the page, or is it literally just what you're showing? In other words, no HTML or anything, just that text.

Comment: Its not HTML. the status page is raw and output is exactly what i posted.

Comment: @Frosa should variable  be created for all reportid or single variable should be used

Answer (score 4):

This should do it:

```
import urllib2


def parse_data(raw_data):  # Name this better
    parsed_data = dict(line.split(':') for line in raw_data.splitlines())
    parsed_data['reportId'] = int(parsed_data['reportId'])
    parsed_data['percent_done'] = int(parsed_data['percent_done'])
    return parsed_data


def get_parsed_data_from_url(url):  # Name this better
    raw_data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    parsed_data = parse_data(raw_data)
    return parsed_data


parsed_data = get_parsed_data_from_url('http://example.com')

# And to loop until status != 'Running', you could do this..

while get_parsed_data_from_url('http://example.com')['status'] == 'Running':
    do_some_stuff()
```

Comment: This solution is nice because it parses the result into a single sane data structure.

Comment: But to point out this only works for the given sample and if there  is slight change it will not work

Comment: @VigneshKalai, true, it could be more generalized; it'll fail if there's no `'reportId'` or `'percent_done'`, or if they aren't `int`'s. I'll modify if OP clarifies any issues.

Comment: @Cyphase just poiting out :) and since it has raw data it can in another format also

Comment: @VigneshKalai, I know; I don't mind having potential issues pointed out :P. I didn't want to overgeneralize the solution based on speculation of possible data; I 'm assuming all the data is relatively similar to the sample in the question, unless told otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

If that is your result and you don't have more HTML as That1Guy commented, you can probably use `startswith` and `endswith`. Something along the lines of (I've skipped a lot of checking and default values here!) ...

```
if line.startswith("reportId:"):
   report_id = line.split(":")[1]

if line.startswith("status:"):
  if line.endswith("Running") == false:
    # abort processing
```

Comment: I think you should add a little strip there

Answer (score 1):

Since you have stable patterns to match to, it's pretty simple:

```
reportIds=[]
# not written here: load report into variable s

for line in s.splitlines():
    if 'reportId' in line:
        reportIds.append(line.split(':')[1])
    if 'status' in line:
        if not line.split(':')[1] == 'Running':
            break
    # not written here: pause for some period of time
```